# Is there a way to write to a property file dynamically from jsp file. I am using spring MVC framework

Tags: spring-mvc, properties-file

Is there a way to write to property file from jsp using spring framework

Answer (score 0):

Not directly and not with spring. And if the property file in in a jar or in a non exploded war, it will be simply impossible.

Anyway you should not even comtemplate changing a property file from the application : a property file contains static data from the application point of view.

If you want to deal with dynamic data, you'd better use a database or dedicated files stored in dedicated directories preferently outside out the war.